# Create custom component based on LinearLayout, declaring layout in XML

Tags: java, xml, android, layout

I've been trying to create a Compound Control in Android 1.5 (as [described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound)) but havn't been able to find any good examples on how to do this using an XML file to specify a layout. I'm fine with creating an Activity and then loading an xml file using the following in the constructor:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

However, I want to do this in subclass of LinearLayout - so I can use this compound component in other XML layouts. Something along the lines of:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout
{
  public CustomView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       setupView();
  }
  public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
      super(context, attrs);
      setupView();
  }
  public void setupView()
  {
    setContentView(R.layout.custom); // Not possible
  }
}
```

What is the correct way of going about doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to "inflate" the layout for your custom view:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, this, true);
```

Comment: So inside my CustomView.java I inflate the xml I want somehow?